# Vectorizing String comparison in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string-comparison

I'm currently starting with python pandas to automize excel manipulation and have some speed problems regarding larger excel files. Now I try to optimize step by step.

The second step in my script creates 3 new columns: error1, error2 or correct.
If there is no information (NaN) in DATE2 only error1 should have the value "x". If there is a value in DATE2 and it is after DATE1 only error2 should have the value "x". If none of these two comparisions hit only correct should have the value "x".

My question is now how to vectorize comparisions like that and how to avoid that whole string casting as I think this is also taking more time.

Code to optimize:

```
#step 2 manipulate excel

import arrow

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if str(row['DATE2']) == "nan":
        df.loc[i, "ERROR1"] = "x"


for i,row in df.iterrows():
    date1str = str(row['DATE1'])[:10]
    date1 = arrow.get(date1str, "YYYY-MM-DD").date()
    if str(row['DATE2']) != "nan":
        date2 = arrow.get(str(row['DATE2'])[:10], 'YYYY-MM-DD').date()
        if date2 > date1:
            df.loc[i, "ERROR2"] = "x"

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if str(row['ERROR1']) == "nan" and str(row['ERROR2']) == "nan":
        df.loc[i, "CORRECT"] = "x"
print("step 2 done...")
```

Code I already tried:

```
def choose(inp):
    if pd.isnull(inp):
        return "x"
    else:
        return ""

df['ERROR1'] = choose(df['DATE2'])
```

The code I tried gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure why you're doing any of this but here you go

```
df['DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE1'], errors = 'coerce')
df['DATE2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE2'], errors = 'coerce')

# Set error1
error1_bool = pd.isnull(df['DATE1']) | pd.isnull(df['DATE2'])
df.loc[error1_bool, 'error1'] = "x"

# Set error2
df_exists = df.loc[~error1_bool, :].copy()
df_exists.loc[df_exists['DATE1'] > df_exists['DATE2'], 'error2'] = "x"
df.loc[~error1_bool, 'error2'] = df_exists['error2']

# Set correct where you haven't set error1 or error2
df.loc[df['error1'] != "x" & df['error2'] != "x", "correct"] = "x"
```